# fstream file fails to read

Tags: c++, tokenize, fstream

I want to pass an fstream object and tokenize the the words. It will always print could not open file in `hasNextToken()` . May someone help me.

//main.cpp

```
int main() {
    string filename = "input.txt";
    fstream inputStream(filename);
    Tokenizer t(inputStream);
    while (t.hasNextToken()) {
    cout << t.nextToken();
 }
}
```

//Tokenizer.h

```
class Tokenizer {
    fstream fin;

public:
    Tokenizer(fstream& file)
    {
        fin << file;
    }

    bool hasNextToken() {
        if (!fin) {
            cout << "Could not open file: " << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        return true;
    }

    string nextToken() {
        string line;
        getline(fin, line);
        if (fin) {
            istringstream sin(line);
            string word;
            sin >> word;
            return word;

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I added it in the initializer list but I get an error about accessing a private member declared in ios.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Tokenizer {
    fstream& fin;

public:
    Tokenizer(fstream& file)
    : fin(file)
    {}

...
}
```

Comment: If I do so I get this error: \fstream(1347): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Comment: This looks like you have missed the change from `fstream fin;` to `fstream& fin;`.

Comment: Thank you, now it print out the text file contents but with extra rubbish.

Comment: You should give an example of input and output. From looking at the code I guess "Could not open file: " will always be printed at the end. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, I can't test it right now, but you can do it quickly:

```
int main() {
    string filename = "input.txt";
    fstream inputStream(filename, ios::in); // add second argument
    // other stuff here
}
```

Cheers